# How to access newly added natural voices in PowerShell after Windows 11 update (2023)

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, text-to-speech

With this simple PowerShell script you could list and then utilize text-to-speech (tts) on Windows:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.speech
$speak = New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
$speak.GetInstalledVoices()|ForEach-Object { $_.VoiceInfo }
```

Which would list the installed TTS voices:

```
Gender                : Male
Age                   : Adult
Name                  : Microsoft David Desktop
Culture               : en-US
Id                    : TTS_MS_EN-US_DAVID_11.0
Description           : Microsoft David Desktop - English (United States)
SupportedAudioFormats : {}
AdditionalInfo        : {[Age, Adult], [Gender, Male], [Language, 409], [Name, Microsoft David Desktop]...}

Gender                : Female
Age                   : Adult
Name                  : Microsoft Zira Desktop
Culture               : en-US
Id                    : TTS_MS_EN-US_ZIRA_11.0
Description           : Microsoft Zira Desktop - English (United States)
SupportedAudioFormats : {}
AdditionalInfo        : {[Age, Adult], [Gender, Female], [Language, 409], [Name, Microsoft Zira Desktop]...}
```

However, the script could not list the newly added natural voices for Narrator after [the latest Windows 11 update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/inside-this-update-93c5c27c-f96e-43c2-a08e-5812d92f220d?OCID=WUSettings#windowsupdate=22631) (2023)

For checking out these languages you could go to `Settings > Accessibility > Narrator`

[image]

Seemingly those are not available in [System.Speech.Synthesis Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis?view=netframework-4.8.1), but do you know how can I access that voices from PowerShell? e.g.: `Microsoft Jenny (Natural)`?

Comment: It's at least worth mentioning that these are mysteriously available in the Edge browser via [speechSynthesis.getVoices()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/getVoices). In my tests, neither Firefox nor Chrome had such availability, much to my chagrin. I realize this doesn't help for this question exactly, but perhaps it can help lead someone to an answer if they're motivated enough.